# what is the sudo password for a --disabled-password user

Tags: ssh, login, sudo, password

I have created an account on ubuntu with the --disabled-password flag.

When I login to this account through ssh using public key authentication, and do a sudo command like apt install, sudo asks for a password. Although I do not know what it is because I disabled the password on the account.

What is the password for sudo on a disabled-password account?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That wont fly... you need a password for the sudo user to be able to disable the sudo password. So that goes the other way round: 1st disable sudo pwd then disabled-password. And I suggest NEVER to do this kind of action w/o a backup sudo user. Leave the 1st sudo user as is. Maybe with a good password (64 chars you generate randomly and store that in an safe). Use a 2nd sudo account to set your method up. That way you can use your 1st sudoer as a fallback.

And you need

```
{user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

in

```
/etc/sudoers.d/{user}
```

If you can't un-disable you can use live session to edit the sudoers file.